# Map visualisation on Pentaho CE

Tags: dictionary, gis, visualization, pentaho, spatial

I am running Pentaho ce 5.3, I already tested it with a star schema cube and  it works fine.

Now I would like to visualize into maps mdx queries on dimensions (including spatial ones) stored in Postgis.

I don't know if it is possible, or should I add any plugin for this matter?

Answer (score 1):

You have more options depending on what do you want to visualize. If you want to show:

- **Map with markers:** I recommand to use `NewMapComponent`. Documentation and example can be found in *Pentaho > Browse Files > Public > plugin-samples > CDE Reference > Map Component Reference*. You can choose different providers of map layer, zoom to any position defined by longitude and latitude, and so on. The `NewMapComponent` *(CDE editor > Components Panel > Custom > NewMapComponent)* configuration:

  - Operation mode: Markers
  - Map Engine: Openlayers
  - Tilesets to display as layers: google
  - Datasource: Need to contain those fields - `City, Longitude, Latitude, Measure` (or `City, Measure`)

[image: NewMapComponent]

- **Map with regions / countries:** I recommand to use `SVG Vector Map` from
  IvyDC - Ivy Dashboard Components plugin (can be downloaded from Marketplace). Which uses this [map library](http://jvectormap.com/maps/world/world/) with world map, coutries map, etc. Documentation and example can be found in *Pentaho > Tools > Ivy Dashboard Components*. `SVG Vector Map` *(CDE editor > Components Panel > Ivy IS > SVG Vector Map)* world map configuration:

  - Map File: World
  - Datasource: Need to contain those fields - `Country, Measure`

[image: SVG Vector Map]

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. Concerning, the visualisation with Map Markers, is it possible for datasource to be a  Point with latitude and longitude (not necessary a city) ? As for the map with regions, could datasource be defined as a shape feature/polygon with geometry? Thanks in advance .

Comment: Yes, longitude and latitude is enough for markers. The `NewMapComponent` allows you to define your own shapes (I haven't tried it yet, so I can't tell you details about the definition.).

Comment: The documentation of the 'Map components Reference' provides different types of datasources, but it is not explicit on how it should be defined. Thank you mzy for helping, appreciate it!