# Using Pentaho CE 5.3 and GeoMap tool

Tags: dictionary, report, visualization, pentaho, geomap

I would like to visualize into maps results of MDX queries on spatial dimensions (representing provinces,clusters,neighborhoods...) stored in Postgis.
I found about the GeoMap component, but I don't know if it's the right tool for this purpose.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Map visualisation on Pentaho CE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29733872/map-visualisation-on-pentaho-ce)

Comment: It concerns using GeoReport & Geomap. My bad for not being clear enough ! I also think that this possibily is not working since it requiers using the Enterprise Edition.